# No puedo usar editcap en la consola de windows

Tags: consola

Error que me aparece al escribir editcap -h --> "editcap" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Obtengo ese error al introducir editcap -h en la terminal de windows, ¿Es por qué solo puede hacerse en Linux o puede haber otro motivo?

Comment: que es editcap??? es un programa de windows???

Comment: Estás mencionando este programa.https://linux.die.net/man/1/editcap